# trying to find largest 4 numbers in giving erray but i dont understand the TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined with my code

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" with my code below

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var max = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var tempMax = arr[i][0];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; i++) {
      var currentElement = arr[i][j];
      if (currentElement >= tempMax) {
        tempMax = currentElement;
      }
    }
    max.push(tempMax);
  }
  return max;
}

largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);
```

Comment: Looks like typo. Best to use array methods like `forEach` and `reduce` to avoid problems with manual iteration (like what you experienced here)

Comment: You are incrementing `i` in the 2nd loop when you should be incrementing `j`

Answer (score 2):

In your code it's a in the inner loop you did `i++` which need to be `j++`

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var max = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var tempMax = arr[i][0];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      var currentElement = arr[i][j];
      if (currentElement >= tempMax) {
        tempMax = currentElement;
      }
    }
    max.push(tempMax);
  }
  return max;
}

let op = largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);

console.log(op)
```

**Alternatively you do it with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator like this**

```js
let arr = [
      [4, 5, 1, 3],
      [13, 27, 18, 26],
      [32, 35, 37, 39],
      [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
    ];
    
let op = arr.map(e=> Math.max(...e));

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `for (var j=0; j<arr[i].length; i++)` to `for (var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++)` in the second loop. You are incrementing `i` in there instead of `j`.